# How can I programmatically store an image in a publicly accessible location on my Drupal site?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am writing a Drupal module where users send down content (formatted as HTML).  The content will almost always include `<img>` tags.  Those tags will reference the user's server.  But, I don't want to hit the user's server every time that content is requested; I want to serve up a version on my server.

So, I have written a function to look through the HTML for `<img>` tags and then use cURL to save them locally.  All is well - except I can't figure out where in my local filesystem to store the images, thanks to Drupal's crazy URL-rewriting.  Ideally I could put them in a directory that is already accessible over the web and not have to create any new directories.

Any thoughts?

TIA,
Benjy

P.S.: Not really feasible to use an `ImageField` as I need to display the image inline.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, you should be able to put them anywhere under the webroot, and they'll be servable, but normally, content images (as opposed to theme images) go in your `files` directory, which is usually configured as `/sites/default/files`. I usually, put a sub-folder to add some structure, so I'd put them in `/sites/default/files/images/scraped` (or whatever).

Note: you can get the file path with [file_directory_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/file_directory_path/6). You might also look at the [file handling api](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/file/6).

Answer (score 0):

why you don't put it in drupal directory? by default, sites/default/files